# SQL limit query

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000

I'm having an issue with limiting the SQL query. I'm using SQL 2000 so I can't use any of the functions like `ROW_NUMBER(),CTE OR OFFSET_ROW FETCH`.

I have tried the `Select TOP limit * FROM` approach and excluded the already shown results but this way the query is so slow because sometimes my result query fetches more than 10000 records.

Also I have tried the following approach:

```
SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT i.name, i.location, i.image ,  
 ( SELECT count(DISTINCT i.id) FROM image WHERE i.id<= im.id ) AS recordnum 
 FROM images AS im 
 order by im.location asc, im.name asc) as tmp 
 WHERE recordnum between 5 AND 15
```

same problem here plus issue because I couldn't add ORDER option in sub query from record um.  I have placed both solution in stored procedure but still the query execution is still so slow.

So my question is:
IS there an efficient way to limit the query to pull 20 records per page in SQL 2000 for large amounts of data i.e more than 10000?

Thanks.

Comment: 10000 records should not be a significant amount (certainly not "large"), check your indexes.  If paging is the issue also consider using a cursor.

Comment: How much data is in the table? Rowcount?

Comment: image table has more than 13 000 000 records :) with adding filters sometimes I pull about 40 000 records

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficient Paging (Limit) Query in SQLServer 2000?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503566/efficient-paging-limit-query-in-sqlserver-2000)

Comment: I don't understand why you are selecting the top 100 Percent? What is this achieving? One way to get an interval of data is to select the Top 15 in a subquery, then reverse the order in the outer query and select the top 10, this will give you records 5-15 of your original order by.

Comment: `DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT`? What on earth is that for?

Comment: ignore that. I wanted to add ORDER BY  in my query for recordnum which requires top, thats why..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the subquery is only run once
where im2.id is null will skip the first 40 rows

```
SELECT top 25 im1.* 
FROM images im1 
left join ( select top 40 id from images order by id ) im2
on im1.id = im2.id
where im2.id is null
order by im1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Query-wise, there is no great performing way. If performance is critical and the data will always be grouped/ordered the same, you could add a int column and set the value by trigger based on the grouping/ordering. Index it and it should be extremely fast for reads; writes will be a bit slower.

Also, make sure you have indexes on the Id columns on image and images.